# Transform two arrays in to one data frame in R

Tags: arrays, r, shiny

I have two arrays coming from a postgreSQL database as following.

```
iarray 
{9.467182035,9.252423958,9.179368178,9.142931845,9.118895803,9.098669713,9.093398102,9.092035392,9.091328028,9.090594437,9.090000456,9.089253543......keeps going on}
varray
{-1.025945126,-0.791203874,-0.506481774,-0.255416444,-0.028424464,0.188855034,0.390787963,0.579327969,0.761521769 ...keeps going on}
```

Both arrays have equal number of entries. I want to convert these to a data frame hence I can draw a graph of i over v.
How should I proceed?

I tried `n<-gsub("^\\{+(.+)\\}+$", '\\1', iarray)` to remove the {} and

`n2 <- strsplit(n, ",")` to remove the commas.

Comment: This looks vaguely like json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are getting iarray & varray as strings :

```
iarray = "{9.467182035,9.252423958,9.179368178,9.142931845}"
varray = "{-1.025945126,-0.791203874,-0.506481774,-0.255416444}"

n<-gsub("^\\{+(.+)\\}+$", '\\1', iarray)
n1 <- strsplit(n,",")
n1 <- unlist(n1)
df <- as.data.frame(n1)
n<-gsub("^\\{+(.+)\\}+$", '\\1', varray)
n2 <- strsplit(n,",")
n2 <- unlist(n2)

df <- cbind(df,n2)
```

Comment: @Nisal This is the correct approach.  The trick here is to `unlist` the output from `strsplit()` to get an actual character vector.

Answer (score 0):

This seems one of the few occasions to correctly use `eval(parse())`:

```
df<-list(iarray,varray)
df<-data.frame(lapply(df, 
    function(x) eval(parse(text=sub("\\}$",")",sub("^\\{","c(",x))))
))
names(df)<-c("iarray","varray")
```

We just replace the `{` with `(`, add a `c` at the beginning and `iarray` and `varray` become command lines to create vectors which we `parse` and `eval`.